# Google play games pop up connection message not showing

Tags: java, android, google-play-services

Hello I have a game application that use Google play games services with the V2 Sdk, the problem is that the user is automatically connected through the games services but the pop-up message saying that the user is connected is not showing. Like this for example : https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3sXV.png

here my code calling the API :

```
    public static ScalingData data;
    private GamesSignInClient gamesSignInClient = PlayGames.getGamesSignInClient(this);
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        PlayGamesSdk.initialize(this);
        init();
        gamesSignInClient.isAuthenticated().addOnCompleteListener(isAuthenticatedTask -> {
            boolean isAuthenticated =
                    (isAuthenticatedTask.isSuccessful() &&
                            isAuthenticatedTask.getResult().isAuthenticated());

            TextView v = findViewById(R.id.textView);
            if (isAuthenticated) {
                PlayGames.getPlayersClient(this).getCurrentPlayer().addOnCompleteListener(mTask -> {
                            v.setText(mTask.getResult().getDisplayName());
                        }
                );
            } else {
                v.setText("User not authenticated");
            }
        });

    }

    private void init(){
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        data = new ScalingData(new Dimension(metrics.widthPixels,metrics.heightPixels));
        try {
            Game g = new Game(this);
            KeyboardManager k = new KeyboardManager(g);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The task you're getting back should have an error stored in it that gives more detail on the error.

You can try something like this :

```
Log.e("Connection", "Unable to connect", isAuthenticatedTask.getException());
```

`getException()` gives you a throwable i.e. something that gives you all the errors.